# ubuntu 16.04 keep restarting when running spark in yarn client mode

Tags: 16.04, restart, error-handling

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 but it is very unstable, and it keeps restarting randomly.

My last random restart was on 02:16 and the following logs from /var/log/syslog may be related to the problem

```
Jun 10 02:16:41 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[10959]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:11718): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Jun 10 02:16:46 Aspire-VN7-791 gnome-session[11134]: (gnome-software:11325): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_add_updates_historical on fwupd: failed to start fwupd: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd': timed out
Jun 10 02:16:46 Aspire-VN7-791 gnome-session[11134]: (gnome-software:11325): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_refine on appstream: Error opening file: Permission denied
Jun 10 02:16:54 Aspire-VN7-791 dhclient[11647]: XMT: Info-Request on wlp7s0, interval 28680ms.
Jun 10 02:17:01 Aspire-VN7-791 CRON[11990]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[15096]: #033[31m[18:16:11.780726 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:449: The connection is closed
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[15096]: #033[31m[18:16:11.797010 CRITICAL]#033[0m zeitgeist_daemon_do_quit: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[15096]: (zeitgeist-daemon:15890): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: The connection is closed
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[15096]: (zeitgeist-fts:15897): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer: The connection is closed
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[15096]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:15897): WARNING **: zeitgeist-fts.vala:252: The connection is closed
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Stopped target Default.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Stopped target Paths.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Stopped target Timers.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jun 10 02:16:11 Aspire-VN7-791 systemd[15007]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 10562 (kill).
```

Can you help to explain what could be the problem?

**Update 1**

My recent crash produces this message in /var/log/syslog

```
Jun 10 12:02:21 Aspire-VN7-791 kernel: [  301.495099] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Does this mean my laptop has hardware problem?

**Update 2**
Ubuntu 16.04 does not support spark in yarn client mode.

I run stress test on my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 but it doesn't crash.

I also tried installing ubuntu 14 and run spark in yarn client mode. It also does not crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 16.04. It seems that you need to install gnome-shell, I don't why it was missing from!

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Update:
It is right that gnome-shell is missing from my Ubuntu  16.04, but the source cause seems to be something else, most probably exhausted memory which I did not have faced wiith Ubuntu 15.1! I will keep updating the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I gave up on ubuntu 16.04, not a good release. I have switched back to 14